# Angular 5 event before change route

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a textarea in which the user enters the text.
at any time it can go over any other link.
So I want that if the input field is not empty and started to change, I want to do this text before the start of the transition and then when the user goes to the dnnmow address that he would continue editing.
for example as implemented on stackoverflow

UPDATE

```
subscribeToChangeRoute() {
    this.changeRoute =  this.router.events.subscribe( (event: Event) => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
        if(mytxtx.length> 0)
          savetxt();
        this.changeRoute.unsubscribe();
      }
    });
  }
```

did so. the method is triggered during the transition.
Also, if you use a `router.url`, you can track the transition from a specific address

Comment: Angular have a life cycle hook for `CanDeactivate` route guard you can take advantage of, you would also probably want to use state management for your input field or any other fields you want to keep track of.

Comment: да спасибо. за подсказку